# path option in redis object of BullModule in @Nestjs/Bull not working

Tags: nestjs

```
//this works fine

   BullModule.forRoot({
         redis: {
           host: herokuRedis.host,
           port: herokuRedis.port,
           password: herokuRedis.password,
           tls: {
             rejectUnauthorized: false,
           },
         },
       }),
//this doesn't work
       BullModule.forRoot({
         redis: {
           path: herokuRedis.path,
           tls: {
             rejectUnauthorized: false,
             path:herokuRedis.tls_path
           },
         },
       }),
```

The latter code basically is not able to connect to redis server and throws after 20 retries which is set as max